# Order Reports empty

Tags: magento-1.7

The order reports only show the header. No content.

I have updated the timezone und refresh statistics, nothing solved the problem.

Comment: Please add more details about it. Have you tried any modifications, used third party plugin etc

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you are hitting PHP memory limit. Try to raise PHP memory_limit option or check web-server logs for errors.